# freezesize is not working ScrollableGridPlugin.js

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

hi freezesize is not working with gridview.My code is

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gridreport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Qareport-gridview" GridLines="Vertical"> </asp:GridView>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=gridreport.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
                    ScrollHeight: 200,
                    freezesize: 2
                });
            })
    </script>
and HTML code is 
 <asp:GridView ID="gridreport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gridreport_RowDataBound" CssClass="Qareport-gridview" GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="true"> 
                    <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No">
                                    <ItemTemplate><%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Netmr">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl0" Text='<%#Eval("Netmr_sn")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proposal">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" Text='<%#Eval("proposal_sn")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maconomy">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl2" Text='<%#Eval("Maconomy_no")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Studies">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl3" Text='<%#Eval("studies")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I want to freeze first two columns in the grid. Tell that what is wrong in my code

Comment: @sukkhvindra what do u mean by not working?

Comment: hi i want to freez first two columns but both are scrolling with the others.

Comment: can you post your markup

Comment: hi @Webruster check this..